# Why aren't views rerendered when the same class object with different values is passed as data source

Tags: ios, swift, macos, class, swiftui

I'm exploring SwiftUI and I've run into something I cannot quite figure out.

I have created a container view that can fetch data on appear as described in [this](https://mecid.github.io/2019/07/31/introducing-container-views-in-swiftui/) post, but instead of completely changing the object referenced in the rendering view, I just load some of its properties.

The loader is an `ObservableObject` that the container view observes. When the loader indicates it(s value) has changed, the container view reloads its `body` property and displays the rendering views with the new data. However, when the object that needs to be loaded is a class, not all subviews in the `body` property reload.

This is some "pseudo"code of my implementation.

```
protocol ValueLoader: Combine.ObservableObject {
    associatedtype Value

    var data: Value { get set }
    func load()
}

struct ValueLoadingContainerView<ValueConsumer: View, 
                                 ValueContainer: ValueLoader>: View {
    @ObservedObject var valueLoader: ValueContainer
    let containedView: (ValueContainer.Value) -> ValueConsumer

    init(_ loader: ValueContainer, 
         @ViewBuilder contained: @escaping (ValueContainer.Value) -> ValueConsumer) {
        self.valueLoader = loader
        self.containedView = contained
    }

    var body: some View {
        containedView(valueLoader.data)
            .onAppear(perform: load)
    }

    private func load() {
        self.valueLoader.load()
    }
}
```

```
class Object {
    let id: String
    var title: String?

    func load(from ...) {
        self.title = ...
    }
}
```

```
struct ConcreteLoader: ValueLoader {
    @Published var data: Object

    func load() {
        guard shouldLoad() else { return }  // To prevent infinite recursion
        ...
        // self.objectWillChange is synthesised by conforming to 
        // ObservableObject and having a property with @Published
        self.objectWillChange.send()          
        self.data.load(from: ...)
    }
}

struct ObjectRenderingView: View {
    let object: Object

    var body: some View {
        Text(object.title ?? "ObjectRenderingView is waiting...")
    }
}
```

```
let object = Object(id: "1", title: nil)

ValueLoadingContainer(ConcreteLoader(object), 
                      contained: { obj in
                          Text(obj.title ?? "Text is waiting...")     // 1
                          Divider()
                          ObjectRenderingView(object: obj)   // 2
                      })
```

When the loader has loaded the properties of `object` it calls the passed `@ViewBuilder` closure with the object again, but now its properties are loaded.

If I add `print` statements, I clearly see that the `contained` `@ViewBuilder` closure is called twice: once with the unloaded object and once with the loaded object. These are the same object, but the second time, the properties have been loaded.

The `Text` label (1) is updated correctly, changing from "Text is waiting..." to the actual title, but the `ObjectRenderingView` (2) does not update its subviews.

The `init` of `ObjectRenderingView` is called with the new data, but the body property is never accessed. This indicates to me that SwiftUI thinks the data has not changed and no rerendering is needed.

I think I understand why it doesn't work: the identity of the `obj` has not changed, so SwiftUI thinks the `ObjectRenderingView` does not need to be reloaded. As the identity of the value `obj.title` has changed from `nil` to the actual title, the `Text` view is reloaded. What I can't figure out is how to get SwiftUI to reload `ObjectRenderingView` as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be a value type. Please take a look at the docs of ObservedObject in Xcode.

> If `Value` is not value semantic, the updating behavior for any views
>   that make use of the resulting `Binding` is unspecified.

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to figure out how to work around this without making my code too ugly. I figured out a way to put my models into structs instead.

My way that would make the code ugly would consist of having a struct wrapper around the class objects and pass those to the rendering views, but I haven't tried this.

Comment: I can't find this statement in the docs, was it removed in Xcode 11 Beta 7?